# Ack/Ag/Pt just list files?

Tags: find, file-search, ack

For a Unix/Unix-like OS...

So, I know I can just use `find .` to list all of the files recursively from the current folder. This includes files I am not interested in.

Using Ack, Ag (silver searcher), or Pt (platinum searcher), is there a way to do the same thing?

I do not want to search inside the files themselves, I just want to list all of the files in my project, without listing the files that these tools ignore for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With both `ag` and `ack` you just provide the `-l` flag.

e.g.

```
$ ag -l foo
file.js
file2.py
```

Comment: This seems to search for files containing "foo". I don't want to search for anything inside the files. Does that make sense? EDIT: oh I see with ag it does seem to list if you don't put the "foo", thanks!

Comment: Ah, in that case you might want to look into the `tree` command.